# DAX POWERPIVOT - Replace blank value with previous

Tags: replace, null, powerbi, powerpivot, dax

I want to replace the blank value with maximum previous value where "DepositLclCcy" is not blank, i.e. 5 in this case for SEK.
How do I write this formula?

Current Result

```
PositionDate    Currency        DepositLclCcy
2017-04-11      SEK               1
2017-04-11      DKK               3
2017-04-11      EUR               7
2017-04-10      SEK               (blank)
2017-04-10      DKK               3
2017-04-10      EUR               5
2017-04-07      SEK               5 
2017-04-07      DKK               3
2017-04-07      EUR               5
```

Desired Result

```
PositionDate    Currency        DepositLclCcy
2017-04-11      SEK               1
2017-04-11      DKK               3
2017-04-11      EUR               7
2017-04-10      SEK               5 
2017-04-10      DKK               3
2017-04-10      EUR               5
2017-04-07      SEK               5 
2017-04-07      DKK               3
2017-04-07      EUR               5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following DAX to create the calculated column:

```
ReplacedDepositLclCcy = 
IF(
    ISBLANK('Table'[DepositLclCcy]),
    CALCULATE(
        FIRSTNONBLANK('Table'[DepositLclCcy], 0),
        FILTER(
            'Table',
            'Table'[PositionDate] < EARLIER('Table'[PositionDate]) &&
            'Table'[Currency] = EARLIER('Table'[Currency]) &&
            'Table'[PositionDate] = LASTDATE('Table'[PositionDate]) &&
            NOT(ISBLANK('Table'[DepositLclCcy]))
        )
    ),
    'Table'[DepositLclCcy]
)
```

So it basically filters the rows with the max `PositionDate` which has the same `Currency` and non-blank `DepositLclCcy`, and return the `DepositLclCcy`. It also works for cases where there are consecutive blank values.

Depending on the data type of `DepositLclCcy` you may need to change `ISBLANK('Table'[DepositLclCcy])` to `'Table'[DepositLclCcy] = ""`.

Results:

[image: results]

Comment: This formula however picks up the first non blank value, say one year back. I want the latest non blank value.

Comment: @Haggan Can you share more about the details? As you can see from the above example it did return the latest non-blank value.